# How do I take Hello world console app and refrence the text for display in a WinForm Label?

Tags: c#, oop

Basically, I'm trying to move the contents of WriteLine to a Label box in a WinForm, as an intro to object oriented programming.  I believe I have some syntax error, and I know the method I have the writeline in is void.  So, any help with getting this to work is appreciated. This is just one of the attempts I've made.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ConsoleHelloWorld.Program;


namespace WindowsFormHelloWorld
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string words = new ConsoleHelloWorld.Program.Main(words);
            label1.Text = words;

        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I'm referencing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleHelloWorld
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string words = "hello world";
            Console.WriteLine(words);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *as an intro to object oriented programming* you'd better read some theory first...

Comment: How about calling a property which returns you the text passed

Comment: Yes as a intro to OOP you defenetly need better example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work.  Turns out I was rooting down incorrectly.  (I had thought rooting worked a bit more like the android file structure.) Basically, I created a separate class for holding the Hello World variable, and just called that for whether I wanted to print the strings to a console or WinForm app.

The initial block of code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleHelloWorld
{


    public static class Program
    {
        public static class Hello
        {
            public static string words = "Hello World";
        }
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           string word = ConsoleHelloWorld.Program.Hello.words;

           Console.WriteLine(word);
           Console.ReadLine();

       }
   }
}
```

The WinForm calling the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ConsoleHelloWorld; //Program.Hello;


namespace WindowsFormHelloWorld
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string word = ConsoleHelloWorld.Program.Hello.words;
            label1.Text = word;

        }
    }
}
```

In future projects I'll just keep the code being run by various environments in it's own project.

Answer (score 0):

Your `words` variable is a **local** one, i.e. its scope is the method where it is declared, that is `Main`. Outside that method you cannot reference it.

For the variable to be accessible, you need to make it a public field (or a property of the class). If you need to access it without having an instance of that class type, than this field should be declared `static`. Then your code would look like this:

```
public static class Program
{
    public readonly static string Words = "hello world";
    //...   
}
```

Assuming the windows application project has a reference to the console application project in the windows application form you may write:

```
string words = ConsoleHelloWorld.Program.Words;
```

Also you don't need to launch the console application, besides you won't manage to do it like this (consider the answer by Cuong Le, if you meant to launch both Console and Windows applications).